# Print fibonacci sequence

Tags: c++, fibonacci, allocation

I'm having trouble printing a matrix with the fibonacci series.
When I start the program, it prints a sequence with an integer and the rest of zeros. I would like a north, to be able to conclude.

Sequential printing function:

```
void printArray(int _A[], int _sz)
{
    _A = new int(_sz);


    cout << ">>> [ ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= _sz; i++)
    {
        cout << _A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << " ]\n";

}
```

Function to calculate the sequence:

```
int fib(int _limit, int *_A)
{
    int count = 0;
    int fib0 = 1;
    int fib1 = 1;
    int fib2 = 0;
    while (fib2 < _limit)
    {
        fib2 = fib0 + fib1;

        count++;  

        fib0 = fib1;
        fib1 = fib2;
    }

    _A = new int(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << _A[i] << " ";
    }

    return count;
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    int L;            
    int *A = nullptr; 
    cout << ">>> Press number: "
    cin >> L; 

    if (L >= 0)
    {
        auto sz = fib(L, A); 
        cout << ">>> The Fibonacci series up to " << L << " is: \n";
        printArray(A, sz); .
    }
    else
        cout << ">>> Sorry, only positive integers accepted. Aborting...\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the phrase "I would like a north, to be able to conclude" means.

Comment: When you start the program it should wait for you to enter a number ;) what input do you use? What output do you get?

Comment: `void printArray(int _A[], int _sz)
{
    _A = new int(_sz);...}` Why? Why overwrite the paramter?

Comment: you assign to `_A` a pointer returned from `new` and then expect to see values when printing `_A[i]` in a loop. why?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to make friends with `std::vector`, your debugger, and your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (get one if you dont have it already), they all will help you here

Comment: Btw. `new int(_sz)` create _one, single_ new integer on the heap with the value `_sz`. maybe you meant to create an array of `_sz` integers -> `new int[_sz]`?

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of issues.

In `printArray` you overwrite the passed in array with a single integer pointer `_A = new int(_sz);`, attempting to print all the elements of the array will be undefined behaviour.

In `fib` you also use `new int(count);`, again this allocates a single pointer rather than array. You should use `new int[count];` instead. You never assign values to the elements of the array `_A` so they are uninitialised and using them is undefined behaviour.

You don't pass the array `_A` back to the calling function. You can fix this by changing the declaration of `fib` to:

```
int fib(int _limit, int *&_A)
```

A good way of fixing all these problems is to use `std::vector` instead of an array, you then don't need to pre-compute the size of the sequence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;

void printArray(const std::vector<int>& A)
{
    cout << ">>> [ ";
    for (int i : A)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << " ]\n";

}

void fib(int _limit, std::vector<int>& A)
{
    int fib0 = 1;
    A.push_back(fib0);
    int fib1 = 1;
    int fib2 = 0;
    while (fib2 < _limit)
    {
        A.push_back(fib1);
        fib2 = fib0 + fib1;

        fib0 = fib1;
        fib1 = fib2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int L;
    std::vector<int> A;
    cout << ">>> Press number: ";
    cin >> L; 

    if (L >= 0)
    {
        fib(L, A); 
        cout << ">>> The Fibonacci series up to " << L << " is: \n";
        printArray(A);
    }
    else
        cout << ">>> Sorry, only positive integers accepted. Aborting...\n";
}
```

If you're taking some perverse computer science course that is teaching you c++ but won't let you use c++ classes then the same code using arrays could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void printArray(int A[], int _sz)
{
    cout << ">>> [ ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= _sz; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << " ]\n";

}

int fib(int _limit, int *A)
{
    int count = 0;
    int fib0 = 1;
    if (A) A[0] = fib0;
    int fib1 = 1;
    int fib2 = 0;
    while (fib2 < _limit)
    {
        count++;
        if (A) A[count] = fib1;
        fib2 = fib0 + fib1;
        fib0 = fib1;
        fib1 = fib2;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int L;            
    int *A = nullptr; 
    cout << ">>> Press number: ";
    cin >> L;

    if (L >= 0)
    {
        auto sz = fib(L, A);
        A = new int[sz];
        fib(L, A);
        cout << ">>> The Fibonacci series up to " << L << " is: \n";
        printArray(A, sz);
    }
    else
        cout << ">>> Sorry, only positive integers accepted. Aborting...\n";
}
```